# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter inside FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm building an events app and this is my cards mockup for each event:

[image]

Now this is my events data from my database. I have an **"events"** node (which contains each event item) and an **"events-users"** node (which contains each user item who is attending the event).

[image]

To get the basic events item (image and name) I have a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and it works good:

```
/**** EVENTS  EVENTS  EVENTS  EVENTS ****/
// Inflates events
RecyclerView mEventsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activity_zone_events_recyclerview);
mEventsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(ZoneActivity.this, 1));
DatabaseReference events = fDatabaseRoot.child("events");
mEventsAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EventItem, EventItemHolder>(EventItem.class, R.layout.item_event, EventItemHolder.class, events) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final EventItemHolder eventItemHolder, final EventItem event, final int position) {

        // Sets event image
        eventItemHolder.setEventImage(event.getEventImage());

        // Sets event name
        eventItemHolder.setEventName(event.getEventName());

        // Sets event OnClickListener
        eventItemHolder.eventCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Opens EventActivity
                Intent eventActivity = new Intent(ZoneActivity.this, EventActivity.class);
                startActivity(eventActivity);
            }

        }
    });

};
mEventsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mEventsAdapter);
```

The **problem** is that I don't know how to get the users items (attendees) inside every card.
I tried by initializing another FirebaseRecyclerAdapter inside the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter I made but the app breaks when I open the corresponding activity... This is what I tried:

```
/**** EVENTS  EVENTS  EVENTS  EVENTS ****/
// Inflates events
RecyclerView mEventsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activity_zone_events_recyclerview);
mEventsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(ZoneActivity.this, 1));
DatabaseReference events = fDatabaseRoot.child("events");
mEventsAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EventItem, EventItemHolder>(EventItem.class, R.layout.item_event, EventItemHolder.class, events) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final EventItemHolder eventItemHolder, final EventItem event, final int position) {

        // Sets event image
        eventItemHolder.setEventImage(event.getEventImage());

        // Sets event name
        eventItemHolder.setEventName(event.getEventName());

        // Sets event OnClickListener
        eventItemHolder.eventCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Opens EventActivity
                Intent eventActivity = new Intent(ZoneActivity.this, EventActivity.class);
                startActivity(eventActivity);
            }

        /**** EVENT-ATTENDEES  EVENT-ATTENDEES  EVENT-ATTENDEES  EVENT-ATTENDEES ****/
        // Inflates event's attendees
        RecyclerView mAttendeesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.item_event_attendees_recyclerview);
        mAttendeesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(ZoneActivity.this, 1));
        mAttendeesAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserItem, UserItemHolder>(UserItem.class, R.layout.item_user, UserItemHolder.class, fDatabaseRoot.child("zones-events").child(zoneKey)) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final UserItemHolder userItemHolder, final UserItem user, final int position) {

                // Sets attendee image
                userItemHolder.setUserImage(user.getUserImage());

            }

        };
        mAttendeesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAttendeesAdapter);

    }

};
mEventsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mEventsAdapter);
```

And this is the **error**:

```
02-27 19:18:53.783 1050-1050/? E/UncaughtException:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                    at com.whatudu.whatudu.ZoneActivity$2$1$1.populateViewHolder(ZoneActivity.java:208)
                                                    at com.whatudu.whatudu.ZoneActivity$2$1$1.populateViewHolder(ZoneActivity.java:141)
                                                    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:184)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5825)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5858)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5094)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4970)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:541)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2843)
```

Any kind of help or tip (if someone has done this before) will be really appreciated! I know this is possible, I just don't know how to do it! :(

Thank you very much in advance.

P.S. GridLayoutManager is selected as the layout style because that's what I was doing previously.

Comment: This line made the error right? `RecyclerView mAttendeesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.item_event_attendees_recyclerview);` Try placing your `mAttendeesRecyclerView` object inside `EventItemHolder` and then you can call created object in this line